# How to check if post has any tag?

Tags: theme-development, themes, tags, conditional-tags

I am displaying post tags like this:

```
<div class="tags"><?php the_tags('<span>Tags</span>' , ' '); ?> </div>
```

It works fine, but if the post does not have any tag, then it adds empty div

```
<div class="tags"></div>
```

So, how can I use the condition to check if post has any tag, then display above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make better use of the parameters:

```
<?php 
the_tags(
    '<div class="tags"><span>Tags</span>', // before
    ' ', // separator
    '</div>' // after
); 
?>
```

Now you will never get any useless markup, because WordPress will not print anything when there are no tags for the current post.

Comment: making use of the integrated parameters is best, therefore +1; to answer your direct question: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/has_tag