# Why Tags don't appear in my page?

Tags: theme-development, tags

I must put the post's tags as a paragraph under the article in my `single.php` page, this is my code:

```
<?php $post_tags = wp_get_post_tags($post->ID);
 if(!empty($post_tags)) {?>
            <p><?php the_tags('', ' ', ''); ?></p>
        <?php } ?>
```

Why it's not working?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check if post has any tag?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/104769/how-to-check-if-post-has-any-tag)

Comment: @AbdulAwal also the code explained in the other question you linked, does not work for me

Answer (score 1):

Run a loop to output your tags:

```
$posttags = get_the_tags($post->ID);
if ($posttags) {
    foreach($posttags as $tag) {
        echo '<a href="'.get_tag_link($tag->term_id).'" title="'.$tag->name.'">'. $tag->name .'</a>'; 
    }
}
```

You don't have to provide `$post->ID` if you are using this inside a loop.