# Hide a div when tags doesnt exist

Tags: php

I'm new to php and struggling to find out how to hide the div if there are no tags on the page.
This is my code:

```
<div class="etichete">
<p><?php the_tags(); ?></p>
</div>
```

Some help please? Thanks.

Comment: This might help you: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/104770/83907

Answer (score 2):

You need to first get and check if there are any tags available, so something like this

```
<?php if (get_tags()) : ?>
<div class="etichete">
    <p><?php the_tags(); ?></p>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

You can also use `!empty(get_tags())` but because if no tags are available it will return an empty array and an empty array is considered falsy, it will not pass the condition and would not display  the `etichete` div.

So in this case `if (!empty(get_tags))` and `if (get_tags())` will work the same way.

Comment: Hi, and thank you for answering. Your code its not working, because the border of the tags is still there even if there are no tags on index page. I have tried this code '<div class="<?php if(the_tags()){echo 'etichete';}?>">' and its working but the css style doesnt work, and i dont know why.

Comment: Are you sure you copied my code exactly? could you edit your question to include the new code you tried to apply?

Comment: I have replaced the "get_tags" with "get_the_tags" and its now working. So thanks for the help.